# In React Native, how do you set the state of a component when you navigate back to it?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I'm trying to navigate from one component to another and then pass parameters back to the original component you started on.

When the data comes back from component B to component A, I want to update the state of component A with that data but I keep getting an error:

> Invariant violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. React limits the
>   number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

**Component A**

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

    // this won't work as it creates an infinite loop
    this.setState({
        property: params.myproperty
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('B')}>
            <Text>Go to B</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

**Component B**

```
render() {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('A', {myproperty: 'something'})}>
            <Text>Back to A</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

Should I be using a different lifecycle hook instead of `componentDidUpdate`? I've seen some people adding a condition around the `setState()`, but I'm not sure how that works.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    const { params } = this.props.navigation.state;

    if(params.myproperty) {
        this.setState({
            property: params.myproperty
        });
    }
}
```

`params.myproperty` won't exist when the component first mounts, so that results in an undefined error. How can I set the state of component A when you navigate back to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
              onPressScreenAFun: (params) => {
                this.screenAFun(params)
              },
            })

screenAFun = (params) => {
console.log(params)
}
```

Screen B:

```
    screenBFun = (params) => {
       const { onPressScreenAFun } = this.props.navigation.navigate.state.params

      onPressScreenAFun(params)
      this.props.navigation.goBack()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling this.setstate in componentDidMount(), handle it in componentWillMount(), it won't create an infinite loop in this way.
For example:

```
componentWillMount() {
  const { navigation } = this.props;

  const myproperty = navigation.getParam('myproperty', '0');
  this.setState({ property: myproperty});            
}
```